# How to apply and merge clipping mask to each separate grouped layer (custom coloring)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, merge

can anyone have solution for my problem, been overthinking how to operate the result. Here is the illustration:
[image: how]
[image]

what if the color is custom, I'm using the main coloring layer for easy/blending brush(colour)
[image]

[image]

Edit: My problem solved!! thx to @Joonas for creating the script https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/013a223e94ba0fb9a2a0?permalink_comment_id=2771421#gistcomment-2771421
[image]

Comment: Is the point here that you want to export each part separately and the new color won't stick when it's applied to a singular parent? I'm thinking you could get pretty close with an `Action`, but a script could get you all the way to the most ideal solution. — I was also thinking it might've been easier if you originally colored each part separately. If you needed to export multiple colors, all you'd have to do is select each color layer and hue & saturation or whatever (maybe), but that might make it more complex if you have multiple fishes.

Comment: Assuming the goal is to export, as I suspected, I do have [a script](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/013a223e94ba0fb9a2a0?permalink_comment_id=2771421#gistcomment-2771421) (at the top) that does something like this, except it saves each layer with the document dimensions. You'd have to do a second run with like `File > Automate > Batch` and an action that trims transparent whitespace... Or edit the script to trim before saving each image which would be a fairly simple change, though you would also have to undo the trim after every save.

Comment: @Joonas  Tried your script, it's works!!!! thx!!!! now I can easily draw on main canvas/layer instead clipped separated layer that takes longer time for post-produiction. ps: can you add scaling? want to scale it to 10x

Comment: no need to edit script for scale features, can do it with image size

Comment: That's what I was thinking. In case you'd need it to happen more or less automatically,  I made you [a code example](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/6fd6836629ec2598c4e7aa5cd2d9b2cd/revisions). The link leads to the "revisions" tab so you can see what I changed. The first change block trims transparent whitespace for each layer, the other block is resizing the doc. Didn't test either. — You could also make an action that resizes the document and then `File > Scripts > Browse...` opens script and that would more or less achieve the same thing (without trimming each output image).

Comment: in my case, no need no trimming or anything, the canvas size is already correct what I wanted after exported. All I did is just select the group and use your script with custom name based on color and it's done. Great job for creating this script! will see your script later!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a clipping mask here. I'd use a **Layer Style**.

You can apply an `Overlay` **Layer Style** to the *group*

[image]

This essentially provides the same result as using a clipping mask.

---

If you want each layer within the group to be *individually* colored.

Right-click the `Effects` item in the Layers panel and choose `Copy Layer Style`. Then *delete* the style from the group.

Then highlight all the layers in the group in the **Layers Panel**, right-click and choose `Paste Layer Style`.

[image]

You can then adjust the layer style on any individual layer to tweak any coloring specifically.

[image]

---

If you're dead set on using a clipping mask, you'll need to *duplicate* the mask for each layer, then merge the clipping mask with each associated layer. Of note, if you use the `Create Layer` option when right clicking a the Layer Styles, you'll see that the overlay Layer Style actually expands to be a clipping mask on the layer (Which You'd need to merge as well to "bake in".)

Comment: what if the color I using is custom? I updated the post

Comment: Again, You would need to duplicate the clipping mask and apply it to each layer necessary. In many cases coloring merely via a clipping mask may not be the best method, depending upon desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple, although just not as asked.

[image]

I have letter A as a layer group. The three lines of the A are separate layers named to Part 1, 2 and 3. Every part contains mostly grey, but also black and white to show they will be not colorized. The layer group has blending mode = Normal. Mode "Pass through" wouldn't keep the color inside the group.

Colorization: Adjustment layer Hue/Saturation with option Colorize=ON makes all non-black and non-white blue:

[image]